# Pull score from online game's HTML

Tags: c#, html, winforms, google-chrome

This is going to be a very weird and oddly specific question. I have a WinForms project that I want to have check the score of an online game. If we're being specific here, I want to pull the player's time from https://www.tetrisfriends.com/games/Sprint/game.php when the game ends. The time is in the website's HTML, and I was wondering if there was any way to periodically check the HTML for a time every few seconds, and if there is one there, pull it into my code. I know that probably made no sense, but please let me know if you have any idea on how I would even start with something like this. Thanks!

(By the way, I don't know if this would simplify it in any way, but I am fine if it just works on a single browser like Chrome)

Comment: Use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). There are [a lot of posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-agility-pack?sort=votes&pageSize=50) that explain how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the site's HTML you can use this code:

```
string urlAddress = "http://google.com";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader readStream = null;

  if (response.CharacterSet == null)
  {
     readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
  }
  else
  {
     readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
  }

  string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

  response.Close();
  readStream.Close();
}
```

And then just search where the score and everything else you want by just how you would search any normal string.

Comment: Would that get the HTML of a currently open window?